# Numpy help needed: how to use boolean values to calculate ranges and add values together within ranges?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix-multiplication, array-broadcasting

I have an Nx2 matrix such as:

```
M = [[10, 1000],
 [11, 200],
 [15, 800],
 [20, 5000],
 [28, 100],
 [32, 3000],
 [35, 3500],
 [38, 100],
 [50, 5000],
 [51, 100],
 [55, 2000],
 [58, 3000],
 [66, 4000],
 [90, 5000]]
```

I need to create a Nx3 matrix, that reflects the relationship of the rows from the first matrix in the following way:

Use the right column to identify candidates for range boundaries, the condition is value >= 1000

This condition applied to the matrix:

```
[[10, 1000],
 [20, 5000],
 [32, 3000],
 [35, 3500],
 [50, 5000],
 [55, 2000],
 [58, 3000],
 [66, 4000],
 [90, 5000],]
```

So far I came up with "M[M[:,1]>=1000]" which works. For this new matrix I want to now check the points in the first column where distance to the next point <= 10 applies, and use these as range boundaries.

What I came up with so far: np.diff(M[:,0]) <= 10 which returns:

```
[True, False, True, False, True, True, True, False]
```

This is where I'm stuck. I want to use this condition to define lower and upper boundary of a range. For example:

```
[[10, 1000], #<- Range 1 start
 [20, 5000], #<- Range 1 end (as 32 would be 12 points away)
 [32, 3000], #<- Range 2 start
 [35, 3500], #<- Range 2 end
 [50, 5000], #<- Range 3 start
 [55, 2000], #<- Range 3 cont (as 55 is only 5 points away)
 [58, 3000], #<- Range 3 cont
 [66, 4000], #<- Range 3 end
 [90, 5000]] #<- Range 4 start and end (as there is no point +-10)
```

Lastly, referring back to the very first matrix, I want to add the right-column values together for each range within (and including) the boundaries.

So I have the four ranges which define start and stop for boundaries.

- Range 1: Start 10, end 20
- Range 2: Start 32, end 35
- Range 3: Start 50, end 66
- Range 4: Start 90, end 90

The resulting matrix would look like this, where column 0 is the start boundary, column 1 the end boundary and column 2 the added values from matrix M from the right column in between start and end.

```
[[10, 20, 7000], # 7000 = 1000+200+800+5000
 [32, 35, 6500], # 6500 = 3000+3500
 [50, 66, 14100], # 14100 = 5000+100+2000+3000+4000
 [90, 90, 5000]] # 5000 = just 5000 as upper=lower boundary
```

I got stuck at the second step, after I get the true/false values for range boundaries. But how to create the ranges from the boolean values, and then how to add values together within these ranges is unclear for me. Would appreciate any suggestions. Also, I'm not sure on my approach, maybe there is a better way to get from the first to the last matrix, maybe skipping one step??

### EDIT

So, I came a bit further with the middle step, and I can now return the start and end values of the range:

```
start_diffs = np.diff(M[:,0]) > 10
start_indexes = np.insert(start_diffs, 0, True)

end_diffs = np.diff(M[:,0]) > 10
end_indexes = np.insert(end_diffs, -1, True)

start_values = M[:,0][start_indexes]
end_values = M[:,0][end_indexes]

print(np.array([start_values, end_values]).T)
```

Returns:

```
[[10 20]
 [32 35]
 [50 66]
 [90 90]]
```

What is missing is somehow using these ranges now to calculate the sums from matrix M in the right column.

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to using `pandas`, here's a solution that seems a bit over-thought in retrospect, but works:

```
# Initial array
M = np.array([[10, 1000],
              [11, 200],
              [15, 800],
              [20, 5000],
              [28, 100],
              [32, 3000],
              [35, 3500],
              [38, 100],
              [50, 5000],
              [51, 100],
              [55, 2000],
              [58, 3000],
              [66, 4000],
              [90, 5000]])

# Build a DataFrame with default integer index and column labels
df = pd.DataFrame(M)

# Get a subset of rows that represent potential interval edges
subset = df[df[1] >= 1000].copy()

# If a row is the first row in a new range, flag it with 1.
# Then cumulatively sum these 1s. This labels each row with a 
# unique integer, one per range
subset[2] = (subset[0].diff() > 10).astype(int).cumsum()

# Get the start and end values of each range
edges = subset.groupby(2).agg({0: ['first', 'last']})
edges
          0     
  first last
2           
0    10   20
1    32   35
2    50   66
3    90   90

# Build a pandas IntervalIndex out of these interval edges
tups = list(edges.itertuples(index=False, name=None))
idx = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples(tups, closed='both')

# Build a Series that maps each interval to a unique range number
mapping = pd.Series(range(len(idx)), index=idx)

# Apply this mapping to create a new column of the original df
df[2] = [mapping.loc[i] if idx.contains(i) else None for i in df[0]]
df
     0     1    2
0   10  1000  0.0
1   11   200  0.0
2   15   800  0.0
3   20  5000  0.0
4   28   100  NaN
5   32  3000  1.0
6   35  3500  1.0
7   38   100  NaN
8   50  5000  2.0
9   51   100  2.0
10  55  2000  2.0
11  58  3000  2.0
12  66  4000  2.0
13  90  5000  3.0

# Group by this new column, get edges of each interval, 
# sum values, and get the underlying numpy array
df.groupby(2).agg({0: ['first', 'last'], 1: 'sum'}).values
array([[   10,    20,  7000],
       [   32,    35,  6500],
       [   50,    66, 14100],
       [   90,    90,  5000]])
```

Comment: Thanks!! But for this specific task I can only use Numpy unfortunately